# How can I refresh a page when a database is updated(Laravel)?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

How can I refresh a page when a database is updated in Laravel?

Comment: What do you mean? Explain more

Comment: please explain more, insert your controller ?

Comment: Like earlier one asked: you need to be more specific. If you don't have access to your database completely - that's one case, and I doubt, that anything could be done. If it's just a part of page that you want to refresh using ajax, then you could return some default value based on request timeout.

Comment: Using a WebSocket.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a rough...open ended question. But here's a stab at it.

Often - the client makes requests to the server to receive state information.  Often its referred to as "client-server architecture" (somewhat erroneously imo).

E.g - Timmy refreshes his webpage and sees different content because the content has changed since the last time he made a request to the server.

Typically - when you want to have a server-client (again...not entirely accurate use of the term) style of communication it requires you to have a socket open with that client. Seeing how you mentioned Laravel, see: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51

Socket libraries often have an "event emitting/broadcasting" behavior.  This would allow you to achieve something like notifying a given client that something has changed in your database :)

Other resources:

[Does anybody still use Client Server Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145527/does-anybody-still-use-client-server-architecture)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/what_is_socket.htm

[What is the difference between a web application and a client/server application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715063/what-is-the-difference-between-a-web-application-and-a-client-server-application)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you need but you probably should to go with Javascript - using AJAX to monitor your tables with certain intervals, and the reload the page when your criteria is met.